# REST API versioning - why aren't models versioned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, versioning, rails-api, semantic-versioning

I've been reading up on all the approaches to version REST APIs. In almost all implementations, controllers and views are versioned, however models are not.

To give the rails example, controllers are organized as:

```
# app/controllers/api/v1/events_controller.rb
class Api::V1::EventsController < Api::ApiController

end
```

Corresponding views as put in at different versioned directories as well. Why don't we version models? Is it because we expect our model (underlying database schema) to not change as the API evolves? What happens when I rename a column name in the database and need a new model to account for that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Models are part of the internals of an application, not its public API. When versioning the key is that the input / output does not deviate.

Maintaining different versioned data in the database - eg data that belongs to different versions of an API is not particularly appealing or practical.

So instead you would use adapters / serializers to adapt the input / output to a particular version of your API while the internals run at the current version.

Lets say you have published an API v 1 in a hurry:

```
GET api/v1/users/:id
  username (String)
  first_name (String)
  lastname (String)
```

After the release you realize that the naming is inconsistent.
So you would create a migration which renames `lastname` to `last_name`.

So API version 2 would have the following signature:

```
GET api/v2/users/:id
  username (String)
  first_name (String)
  last_name (String)
```

But this should break a test for the `API v1` since the response no longer contains `lastname`.

So to fix it we would create something like:

```
class Api::V1::UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :username, :first_name, :lastname

  def lastname
    object.last_name
  end
end
```

Comment: The example stated too specific to GET use case which holds good here. Can you please answer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303966/why-not-to-consider-models-in-rest-api-versioning?

Comment: @ayyappa what is that you want? Your question has an excellent answer

Answer (score 5):

> Why don't we version models?

Models typically are closely aligned with the database schema. Typically the database is a canonical data store shared by all versions of APIs, hence it does not make much sense to version the models.

Plus, in Rails applications, often the bulk of buisness logic resides in the models. Versioning models would require either replicating the logic or addition of another layer of abstraction which introduces maintenance overhead.

> Is it because we expect our model (underlying database schema) to not change as the API evolves?

No. Database schema can and does change very often.

> What happens when I rename a column name in the database and need a new model to account for that?

You don't introduce a model to account for schema changes. You adapt the existing model to accomodate the change, and then modify the implementations of prior APIs so the previous version clients continue getting the response in the same format as they expected before.

Since this mapping of your buisness entities (models) to API responses, happens in controllers (or serializers, or json templates - depending on your preferred implementation) -- these parts of your application will have to be modified to ensure backward compatibility.